# Dynamodb transaction limits increase

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Currently, I need to update two tables in concurrency and one table contains configurations and other table include items to the configuration link. Now whenever the configuration is updated, it provides me with the list of items that are belong to this configuration(it can be 100-1000 items or more). How can i update the dynamodb using transaction?

Answer (score 1):

> I need to update two tables in concurrency

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/transaction-apis.html

> `TransactWriteItems` is a synchronous and idempotent write operation that groups up to 25 write actions in a single all-or-nothing operation. These actions can target up to 25 distinct items **in one or more DynamoDB tables** within the same AWS account and in the same Region. The aggregate size of the items in the transaction cannot exceed 4 MB. The actions are completed atomically so that either all of them succeed or none of them succeeds.